# How to figure out what's the size of ListState?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

In my Flink project, there are two topics that I join query on both of them:

```
   StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
   StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

   env.setStateBackend(new EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend());
   env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("file:///...");

KafkaSource<DataFileChunk> src1 = KafkaSource.<DataFileChunk>builder().            
 setBootstrapServers("pkc-ep9mm.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092").setTopics("topic1").... 

KafkaSource<DataFileChunk> src2 = KafkaSource.<DataFileChunk>builder().            
 setBootstrapServers("pkc-ep9mm.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092").setTopics("topic2)....
```

Following there are two corresponding dataStreams and process Functions:

````
DataStream<DataFileChunk> stream1 = env.fromSource(src1, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "TBL1");

DataStream<DataFileChunk> stream2 = env.fromSource(src2, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "TBL2");```

 tableEnv.createTemporaryView("TBL1", rawDataStream);
 tableEnv.createTemporaryView("TBL2", bkgdDataStream);

String join_query = "select ....";
Table join_table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(data_query);

DataStream<Row> join_stream = tableEnv.toDataStream(raw_table);

join_stream.process(new DataProcessor()).setParallelism(4);
````

My ProcessFunction class:

```
public class DataProcessor
        extends ProcessFunction<Row, List<double[][][]>> implements CheckpointedFunction, SinkFunction<Tuple2<double[][][], double[][][]>> {

    @Override
    public void processElement(Row row, ProcessFunction<Row, List<double[][][]>>.Context context, Collector<List<double[][][]>> collector) throws Exception {

int id = Integer.parseInt("" + row.getField(0));
String data_chunk1 = "" + row.getField(1);
String total_chunk2 = "" + row.getField(2);
int chunk_size = Integer.parseInt("" + row.getField(3));

double[][][] p_data1 = analyzeData(id, data_chunk1, chunk_size);
double[][][] p_data2 = analyzeData(id, data_chunk2, chunk_size);

listState.add(new Tuple2<>(p_data1, p_data2));

//        TODO: 
//         1. Ensure to consume all data and add them to the listSate 
//         2. Iterate over listSate...
//         3. Clean listState
}

    private transient ListState<Tuple2<double[][][], double[][][]>> listState;
    
    @Override
    public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
        ListStateDescriptor<Tuple2<double[][][], double[][][]>> descriptor =
                new ListStateDescriptor<>(
                        "buffered-elements",
                        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<>() {
                        }));

        listState = context.getOperatorStateStore().getListState(descriptor);
    }
}
```

listState does not provide me with a method to figure out what's the size of the list. So, I will have two options:

Option 1: Figuring out that somehow all data are consumed and then iterate over the listState (but don't know how to do that...)

Option 2: Calculation the size of the list in another state (i.e. ValueState). From this option, by reading [this article](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/) I learned a bit about **ValueState** and **Keyed DataStream**.

So, I think I will need to follow these steps:

1. Creating a KeySelector. I tried this but it might be wrong:

```
join_stream.keyBy((KeySelector<Row, Integer>) row -> Integer.parseInt("" + row.getField(0)));
```

2. Initializing a ValueState somehow as it needs to be pointed out to my listSate to get the size of listSate anytime.**

So, I don't know how to implement the above steps.

Comment: Unfortunately it's unclear from your description WHY you need to know the list size, because it's not clear what you're trying to do in the ProcessFunction. Plus you're mixing Table and DataStream APIs, which further muddies the water.

Comment: Also why is your ProcessFunction implementing CheckpointedFunction and SinkFunction?

Comment: Answer your questions:

Comment: 1)  I will need to calculate the listSize to make sure once it equals "chunk_size", pass those objects p_data1 & p_data1 into another function for further data analysis.  2) My messages are coming from two different topics. So, I will need to pass the join into DataStream and process it within ProcessFunction. 3)  My ProcessFunction needs to be implemented CheckpointedFunction to access overridden initializeState method to "listState = context.getOperatorStateStore().getListState(descriptor);".

Answer (score 0):

ListState does not provide a method to calculate the size of the list. Therefore, I ended up creating a ValueState as a counter, as:

```
private transient ValueState<Integer> count;
```

where

```
ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> countDescriptor;
        countDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<Integer>(
                "counter",
                Types.INT,
                1); // default counter value is 1
        count = getRuntimeContext().getState(countDescriptor);
```

Inside the processElement method:

```
Integer cnt = count.value();
count.update(cnt + 1);
```

The most important part is how to create a **[KeySelector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/functions/KeySelector.html)**
Since there are two different topics (Kafka) and my query is a join on both tables and also my **[DataStream](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html)** is an instance of **[Row](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/types/Row.html)**, my KeySelector should be an instance of Row. To create a **key**, I figured out which field gives me a unique value. Therefore:

```
join_stream.keyBy((KeySelector<Row, String>) row -> String.valueOf(row.getField(2)).
process(new DataProcessor()).setParallelism(4);
```